# Вернуть объект из функции js

Tags: javascript, объекты

Есть некая функция

```js
switch (icons)
    case "car"
return iconset.car
    case "phone"
return iconset.phone
    case "app"
return iconset.app
```

Иконок в объекте iconset будет довольно много. Как можно упростить данную функцию не перебирая все варианты с помощью switch
по сути необходимо сделать return iconset.icons, где в переменной icons и лежит нужное значение, не понимаю на концептуальном уровне как такое сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя "скобочное" обращение к свойствам:

```
return iconset[icons];
```

Comment: Ведь сколько ни пиши задают и задают этот вопрос. :))

Comment: Спасибо. Немного стыдно, что сам не пришел к такому)) Самоучка)) А по поводу задают, так ведь сложно сформулировать сам запрос что бы ответ найти.